# Restricting transferability of Smart Contracts

Tags: smartcontracts

Can a smart contract be created which can be exchanged once at point of sale, and only transferred subsequently through a single approved exchange? Can that be written into the contract itself?

Comment: Hopefully Bitcoin's answer below helps, but you may get a more specific answer if you ask a more specific question. What Smart Contract Platform are you using? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Bitcoin script only allows the conditions under which an output can be spent to be controlled, it does not provide a method for dictating what can happen to the output once these conditions have been satisfied. The concept you are describing is called a [coin covenant](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=278122.0;all), the linked thread goes into some detail explaining why this is generally a bad idea.